# Accessing different image copy based on which div image is in

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, optimization

So i used my own tweak of `im-optimize.py` to create different copies of the same image to be displayed on different posts.

So lets say i have 2 image div sizes.

```
a) 100*100 
b) 10*10
```

So if an image lies in div a. the copy optimized (lies in a directory on the server)for 100*100 div needs to be accessed

For more clarity, say images for a lies in `uploads/a/` and for b in `/images/b`.
Any help?

Is it even feasible to do this?

Comment: can't you just reference different files in each div? cheers

Comment: exactly what i am asking. i am a noob.haha. can you give me reference?

Comment: a simple src reference would do? i would need to check if that works easily on wordpress

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="a">
    <img src="/images/image-100.jpg">
</div>

<div class="b">
    <img src="/images/image-10.jpg">
</div>
```

If I got you right, that's what you want! Cheers